# VBA using loop store value in string

Tags: vba, loops

How to store the value of A1 to A5 to the string "Content" not only the A5 value ??

```
i = 2
Do
Content = "Range("A" & i).Value"
i = i + 1
Loop Until i > 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then yo need to concatenate it with itself:

```
i = 2
Do
  Content = Content & Range("A" & i).Value
  i = i + 1
Loop Until i > 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this:

```
Dim r As Range, Content As String
Set r = Range("A1:A5")
With Application
    Content = VBA.Join(.Transpose(r), "")
    Debug.Print Content
End With
```

No Looping required. That is if you only need to concatenate it.